# parallel call using rxjava 1

Tags: java-8, rx-java

Scenario - To make a service call for certain items (suppose 4 items) which will update DB. Sequence doesn't matter. All service calls are independent of each other but wait till all the calls are completed, so want to go for parallel calls using rxjava 1.x

Now, the problem that I'm facing is update service doesn't return anything if it is successful.

```
public class DbClient {
  public void update(SomeObject someObject) {
  //update logic
  }
}

//client code to call update method

public void processUpdate(Map<String, SomeObject> map) {
 map.entrySet.stream.forEach(entry -> {
    dbClient.update(entry.getValue()); // how can I call this parallely using rxjava 1.x
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that RxJava 1 is outdated and no longer supported or maintained as a library.

You can `flatMap` each map element onto its own reactive action to have them run concurrently:

```java
Observable.from(map.entrySet())
.flatMap(entry -> 
    Observable.create(emitter -> {
        dbClient.update(entry.getValue());
        emitter.onCompleted();
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
    true, // <------------ aggregate all errors
    8 // <---------------- number of concurrent updates you want
)
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. I'll definitely try this approach.

Currently, I managed to do that parallel call using Completable.fromAction(). But your approach seems more clean :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap` operator for parallel executing. Create `List<Observable>` using `map` and then executes them using `Observable.flatMap`. Focus on `it.subscribeOn` line. The line changes **sequence** to **parallel**.

Refer to [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3532)

```
public class MultipleExecutes {
    public class DbClient {
        Observable<String> update(String someObject) {
            // replace what you want.
            // Observable.fromCallable() <- consider this
            return Observable.just(someObject);
        }
    }

    // client code to call update method
    private List<Observable<String>> processUpdate(Map<String, String> map) {
        DbClient dbClient = new DbClient();

        return map
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(entry -> dbClient.update(entry.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("1", "1");
        map.put("2", "2");
        map.put("3", "3");
        map.put("4", "4");

        List<Observable<String>> o = new MultipleExecutes().processUpdate(map);
        Observable
                .fromIterable(o)
                .flatMap(it -> it.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())) <-- important line
                .subscribe(System.out::println);

        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Output

```
4
1
2
3
```

Comment: You should not do blocking calls on the computation scheduler. Also `fromIterable` is  in 2.x and the question was predicated on 1.x.